# Android Studio Java app crashing when trying to update TextView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to create a new Thread that updates a TextView's value every 1 second and for some reason this code crashes the app

```
new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            try {
                while(!this.isInterrupted()){
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                            TextView tvLegajo = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.txtLegajo));
                            TextView tvNFabrica = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.txtNFabrica));
                            if(App.getInstance().getLegajoAlumno()!=0)
                                tvLegajo.setText(App.getInstance().getLegajoAlumno());
                            else
                                tvLegajo.setText("");
                            tvNFabrica.setText(App.getInstance().getnFabricaNotebook());
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

That is in the onCreate function in my MainActivity
Just to clarify, I'm trying to update the values in the Views

```
R.id.txtLegajo 
R.id.txtNFabrica
```

to the values in

```
App.getInstance().getLegajoAlumno();
App.getInstance().getNFabricaNotebook();
```

(also if the ...getLegajoAlumno() is 0, R.id.txtLegajo is set to a blank String)

**EDIT:**

I did the changes recomended by @DiLDoST but it crashes regardles.
A detail is that the thread is created in the onCreate method of the activity.
The logcat after the crash looks like this:

```
2022-09-12 10:50:39.696 11067-11067/com.example.prestaciones E/le.prestacione: Invalid ID 0x000368bd.
2022-09-12 10:50:39.696 11067-11067/com.example.prestaciones D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2022-09-12 10:50:39.697 11067-11067/com.example.prestaciones E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.prestaciones, PID: 11067
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x368bd
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:367)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6370)
        at com.example.prestaciones.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:47)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
2022-09-12 10:50:39.720 11067-11067/com.example.prestaciones I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11067 SIG: 9
```

Comment: `Resources$NotFoundException` means whatever this`App.getInstance().getLegajoAlumno()` (and the other) are outputting, are numbers and as such, `TextView.setText(...)` is trying to resolve it as a string resource and naturally failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `tvLegajo.setText(App.getInstance().getLegajoAlumno());` is being resolved to a `number`. This means the `setText` method is thinking it's a Resource Id. Because it's not, then you get a Resource Not Found exception.

Instead make it a string: `getLegajoAlumno().toString()`.

Comment: I'm ashamed of not noticing, ty

Answer (score 0):

**ISSUE:** I guess your issue is calling `setContentView` again and again...

**FIX:** `setContentView` and assign Variables in `onCreate`:

```
TextView tvLegajo;
TextView tvNFabrica;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tvLegajo = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.txtLegajo));
    tvNFabrica = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.txtNFabrica));
}
```

Now start your thread:

```
    new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            try {
                while(!this.isInterrupted()){
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if(App.getInstance().getLegajoAlumno()!=0)
                                    tvLegajo.setText(App.getInstance().getLegajoAlumno());
                                else
                                    tvLegajo.setText("");
                                tvNFabrica.setText(App.getInstance().getnFabricaNotebook());
                            }
                        });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

**PERFECT CURE:** Its better if you show us the error from [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat), so we can help to fix it in a better way.

Comment: did this, look at edited mainPost

Comment: Yeah, the issue is as @Martin said. So... If i could help, kindly don't forget to vote me too